# Babel configuration with decorators & class properties not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I have a simple class which needs to be tested using Jest.
The babel configuration for the project I am using -

Babel version - 7

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-classes",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ]
  ],
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/react"]
}
```

I am getting an error -

```
  SyntaxError: Missing class properties transform.
  5 | 
       6 | export default class Template {
    >  7 |   id;
```

Answer (score 2):

So, I figured out the issue
@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators should come before @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"],
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```